# When Media Player's windowlessVideo Param goes bad, now what?

Tags: html, windows, windows-7, media-player, windows-media-player

***Background:***

We have a web "app", where on one web page we have the following:

An embedded Windows Media Player object.  It's surrounded by listview's on the left, and some graphical elements on the bottom.  The listview's (there are a couple), allow for data entry.  Therefore, dialogs pop up to allow you to enter in various text.

Because of these pop-up dialogs (not only the data entry dialogs, but regular alerts/MessageBoxes), one of the params of the embedded Windows Media Player object is:

```
<param name="windowlessVideo" value="true">
```

Otherwise, any dialog of any type will fall behind the Media Player object and you won't be able to see it. [Here's an example stackoverflow solution to the dialog problem using windowlessVideo.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602366/windows-media-player-on-top-other-div)

***Here's the issue:***

And we didn't see this until more and more people started using Windows 7 and Windows Media Player 12, with the windowlessVideo setting on, it causes performance to degrade.  Sort of a lag.  Not the type of lag where I type a few words, a second goes by, and then you see the words that I typed finally appear.  No.  Imagine typing this sentence:

**I am typing into a dialog box some text.**

When you look up, various characters will be missing and it will look something like:

**amtpin int adilg box sme txt.**

So, as you can imagine, this is unacceptable.  People just can't type into the dialogs anymore.

Of course, when you look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says this:

> In Windows Vista, rendering video in windowless mode can degrade
>   performance.

OK, yep.  I see it.  Now what?

Before Windows Media Player 12, I used to be able to go to Tools -> Options -> Performance tab and under Video acceleration there would be a slider, and an Advanced button with a ton of other options.  I've fixed a 'flickering' video problem before by turning the slider to None.  So, I was hoping there was some Media Player setting I could modify to rectify this.  Nope.  There are no longer any video acceleration settings, and there are like 4 checkboxes under 'DVD and video playback' that don't affect things.

Meanwhile, if all I do is remove the windowlessVideo setting, I don't get that lag at all.  I add it back, I get the lag.  I take it away, no lag.  But all that does is replace one problem with another.  I might fix the lag, but now all my dialogs are behind the Media Player.

OK, Microsoft.  Thanks!  You win.  But, now what?  Anybody have any ideas?  Thanks!